# How to reinject the packet in the Iptables?

Tags: c, routes, iptables

I have a packet inside a packet a.k.a tunneling. So it's of the form [IP HEADER 1][IP HEADER 2][PAYLOAD]. After reading the first header(done by a library) I will get the packet with [ IP HEADER 2] at the INPUT chain of the iptables. I want to re-inject the packet to the starting of the iptables i.e. in the PREROUTING chain. Ultimate aim is to forward the packet to a remote host (that's why I want the packet to be in the PREROUTING chain). I have read something about the libipq but I am not really sure that it is the best way to do it.

Comment: nfnetlink_queue has replaced ip_queue (with libnetfilter_queue instead of libipq).  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nfqueue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there may be some add-on target to do this. My gut feeling is that you would use the `MARK` target to mark this packet then use `iproute2` to set up the routing of where you want it to go.

Something like:

```
iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.2 -j MARK --set-mark 0xAA
```

`ip rule add fwmark 0xAA table Reroute_Tunnel`

Then it's up to you to add and decide what the `Reroute_Tunnel` table does

Comment: will try it, looks promising.